# Filtering a particular value in an array inside a key value pair

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

From a given Object I need to filter out cities based on user typing.

I have an object :

```
arr= [
    {'country':'india','cities':['bangalore','chennai']},
    { 'country': 'USA' , 'cities': ['New yourk','Chicago'] }
  ]
```

By default it will show each country and value in html. When user types a value in input, I need to show only the 'cities' which are matching the input.

Here is the link :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxaa7b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

When somebody starts typing something I need to show the cities result matching the user input.

Comment: If I start typing I then all the cities starting/ having I. Filtering with first letter or middle letter is not a problem, that I will handle, Problem is using map() and filter() is returning array inside array for which it is not shown in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should of checked your stackblitz, in your particular case:

```
res=this.arr.map(e=>({...e, cities: e.cities.filter(city => city.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1)}))
```

Comment: It does return the value but the country property is unnecessarily showing. Can I show only the cities and not anything else

Comment: Actually ya I got that. Removed the spread operator and it worked as required

Answer (score 1):

```
filteredArray = input.valueChanges.pipe(
 map(inputValue => arr.filter(arrValue => arrValue.startsWith(inputValue)))
);
```

And use an async pipe on the filteredArray.

Comment: Seems perfect answer, would be more better if you put this logic into some kind of custom pipe :)

Comment: a pipe using an input value would be an impure pipe, I'd recommend against it.

Comment: Getting error " Property 'valueChanges' does not exist on type '{ 'country': string; 'cities': string[]; }[]'."

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  display = [];
  arr = [
    { 'country': 'india', 'cities': ['Bangalore', 'Chennai'] },
    { 'country': 'USA', 'cities': ['New York', 'Chicago'] }
  ]
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor() {
    this.display = this.arr;
  }


  search(e) {
    let input = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    // this.display = input ? this.filter(input) : this.arr;
    this.display = input ? this.filterByArrayMethods(input) : this.arr;
  }

  filter(val) {
    let res = [];
    this.arr.forEach(countryObj => {
      const countryToAdd = {
        country: countryObj.country,
        cities: countryObj.cities.filter(city => city.toLowerCase().includes(val))
      };
      if(countryToAdd.cities.length > 0) {
        res.push(countryToAdd);
      }
    });
    return res
  }

  filterByArrayMethods(val) {
    return this.arr.reduce((accumulator, countryObject) => {
      const citiesInTheCountry = countryObject.cities.filter(cityName => cityName.toLowerCase().includes(val));
      if (citiesInTheCountry.length > 0) accumulator.push({ ...countryObject, cities: citiesInTheCountry })
      return accumulator;
    }, []);
  }


}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-based-on-city-name?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: I was rather looking at a short solution using filter(), map() or reduce() whichever are used.

Comment: your function  " filterByArrayMethods()" that kinda solution I was looking for using chaining together of map() and filter(). can that be achieved?

Comment: @UdG I've updated my answer and the StackBlitz with `reduce` if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I accepted one above as it fulfilled my requirement. But your answer is also worth looking and i will keep it as a reference for other use cases. thanx